Failed to establish a new connection : Error 110 - Connection timed out with Salesforce Airflow connection
I am trying to connect to Salesforce using Simple Salesforce bulk operator in Airflow.
I have created the connection using the Airflow Ui for Salseforce using the connection type http and provide all the required values. But keep getting - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out.
Max retry exceeded.
Any help please
